# Submenu being cut off

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, submenu

I was asked to update the website at my marketing position and I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm totally taking over a website made by some random dude many years ago, who I have no ability to contact. I know basic coding, but have not done anything in *years*, so please be nice and bear with me!

My problem is that my submenu is being cut off at the very bottom. I've tried playing with margins and all that fun stuff, but no matter how long the actual submenu is, it always cuts off the bottom. I've been messing with this for days now--and it's probably something very simple, but I just can't seem to figure out what it is.  Can anyone help?

Photo of the problem:
http://postimg.org/image/q65qcst1x/

Actual website:
http://www.lkpb.com

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `clip: rect(0 253 420 0);` CSS property and increase the height of the menu item.

Example CSS:

```
#menu25Container,
#menu25Content  {
     position: absolute;
     width: 253px;
     height: 450px;
     //clip: rect(0 253 420 0); This to be removed
}
```

You may have to do the same with all the menu items if the same problem persists.

Comment: You are a saint, Jamie Read!  Especially because I just realized I didn't even post the navigational page...thanks for taking the time to help out the new kid!

Comment: @user2932513 Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark me as the answer :) Thanks.